# Función .click con setTimeout

Tags: javascript

**Resumen**

Estoy intentando por JS dar click a un boton luego que trascurra 5 segundos, me informe y se debe usar la funcion .click con la funcion de setTimeout pero no me funciona; no veo que transcurran los 5 segundos, miro en la consola y no me salen errores, saben porque ?

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function() {
          document.get
ElementById('BtnCerrarChat').click();
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Puedes crear un snippet en tu pregunta, qué acción debe desencadenar el botón? Es el único elemento con ese valor de ID? Haz clic en [edit] y agrega un [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, intenta usar una funcion flecha, y tambien recuerda revisar tu html y que tu boton si tenga el id que estas mandando a buscar, tambien que tu boton si tenga en `onClick` la funcion que se quiere ejecutar asi como importar tu javascript en tu html como se debe.

Saludos

Test

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementById("clickMe").click()
}, 5000);

function myGreeting() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
}
```

```html
<p>Wait 5 seconds for the greeting:</p>

<button id="clickMe" onClick="myGreeting()">Click</button>

<h2 id="demo"></h2>
```